# Question on approximation by smooth functions in Sobolev Space

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

Quite a small question. In Evan's PDEs he states the following theorem

> Assume $U$ is bounded and $\partial U$ is $C^1$. Suppose $u\in W^{k,p}(U)$ for some $1\leq p<\infty$. Then there exist functions $u_m\in C^\infty(\bar{U})$ such that
> $$u_m\to u \ \ \ \ in \ W^{k,p}(U)$$

I presume theis theorem will still hold if $u_m\in C^\infty_c(U)$. My main question is, does this require convergence for 'any' sequence? Or is it sufficient to have convergence for 'a' sequence.

Comment: I don't understand your question. What do you mean "does this require convergence for 'any' sequence"?

Comment: Sorry @JackyChong. What I am trying to say is, is it sufficient to approximate $u$ by smooth functions by a single sequence $u_m$? Or does this $u_m$ have to converge to $u$ for every sequence $u_m$?

Comment: The theorem says there exists one sequence.

Comment: @JackyChong If we have a Sobolev space that is a subset of $L^p(U)$, then why couldn't we choose $u_m$ to be a Cauchy sequence. And since $L^p(U)$ is complete, $u_m \to u$ in the Sobolev space.

Comment: Why would the limit be in the Sobolev space?

Comment: Also, just a reminder, the norm on the Sobolev space is not the same norm on $L^p(U)$.

Comment: @JackyChong wouldn't you always be able to construct a sequence such that it does converge? As long as $W^{k,p_1}(U)\subset L^{p_2}(U)$ for a particular $k,p_1,p_2$?

Comment: Since $W^{k, p}(U) \subset L^p(U)$, then any Cauchy sequence $\{u_m\}$ in $W^{k, p}(U)$ is a Cauchy sequence in $L^p(U)$ because $\|u_m\|_{W^{p, k}}\ge \|u_m\|_{L^p}$. Then $u_m\rightarrow u \in L^p(U)$ since the space is complete. However, is $\|u\|_{W^{k, p}}$ finite? Not necessary. Think of a smooth function converging to a step function. Clearly the derivative is unbounded.

Comment: @JackyChong If the sequence was in $C^\infty_c(U)$ then it would be smooth and bounded since it has compact support right? Would this give guaranteed convergence of a sequence $u_m\subset C^\infty_c (U)\to u \in W^{k,p}(U)$? Assuming the same conditions as previous?

Comment: You can construct a family of smooth functions that converges to a $\delta$ function which is not even in $L^p(U)$ for $p>1$, let alone in $W^{k, p}(U)$.

Answer (score 1):

The claim is no longer true in general if you replace $u_m \in C^\infty(\bar U)$ by the stronger condition $u_m \in C_c^\infty(\Omega)$.
In fact, this is only possible for $u\in W^{k,p}_0(U)$, since this space is defined as the closure of $C_c^\infty(\Omega)$ in $W^{k,p}(U)$.

The intuition behind that is that functions in $W^{k,p}(U)$ and $C^\infty(\bar U)$
can have non-zero boundary values, which is not true for $C_c^\infty(\Omega)$.